# how to get my .cpp file in doxygen documentation too?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have a c++ project in which I have 2 .hpp files and their .cpp files, I commented all of them but when I run Doxygen I only get .hpp files ? any idea how can i get my source files too ? is possible at least ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DoxyWizard, go to `Expert->Input` then scroll down to `FILE_PATTERNS`. Make sure the `.cpp` extension is listed. If not, insert it into the list.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try generating the doxygen config file and then see if you'd like to modify anything?

```
doxygen -g "config_file_name"
```

Then run doxygen as follows:

```
doxygen "config_file_name"
```

Comment: I'm you the GUI of Doxygen